# Google cloud enterprise recaptcha works locally but not in production

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, recaptcha-v3

I recently integrated a google cloud enterprise recaptcha on to my app but it seems not to work when deployed.

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/set-up-google-cloud#linux-or-macos . Had the same issue locally but i was able to make it work by following the steps in the above url. Question is, how do i get this to work in production also using ci pipeline(github Actions)

it return a `PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied for: recaptchaenterprise.assessments.create. Please ensure you have sufficient permissions: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access` when deployed.

Comment: I have the same issue at the moment. Did you manage to get it work?

Comment: yes. u need to create a client from the RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient clas then call client.initialize()